# Running python portably from usb drive

Tags: python, usb-drive

I want to download the Python on my Ubuntu 12.04, but I run it on USB flash drive. Do I have any choice to let the Python download on my flash drive? FYI it is my first time touching Ubuntu so try to make it simple.

Comment: You want to run python portably?

Comment: @Anwar I think he need persistent mode , right ?

Comment: Python is already included in Ubuntu. You don't need to install it.

Comment: what OS are you trying to use python under?  portable python is more popular on windows since it's not included by default.  on the linux side it's more on the programmer to include or require dependencies as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run python in Ubuntu, just open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and execute this command

```
python
```

Then you will have an interactive python interpreter running in the termnal.

I am assuming you want to run python portably from the USB drive and use it anywhere with Linux system. You can achieve this by [downloading portable python from this site](http://www.portablepython.com/)

1. [Download it](http://www.portablepython.com/wiki/Download)
2. Install it to your USB drive

   I am quoting from the site

   > Portable Python can be installed on any USB storage device, local hard drive or network location. It is possible to install several different distributions of Portable Python on the same USB storage device (or local hard drive) and have them running side by side. This makes Portable Python ideal environment to test your code with different Python engines.
3. Then run from the USB directly to program python

Enjoy Portable Pythonning!!

Comment: But how can I run the Python in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Frontier_Alex I updated my answer

Comment: Jus a note: Portable Python is discontinued. Last installer is for Python 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save the Software installing on Live USB Ubuntu with Live Persistent mode . for more information click at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Comment: python is already included in Ubuntu

Comment: @Anwar yes you right again :P